# How to construct a subring of a polynomial ring in Magma

Tags: symbolic-computation, computer-arithmetic

This is a question about the computer algebra system [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/). I have been looking for a place to ask this type of question on the SE network and scicomp.SE [was suggested to me](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22052/is-either-math-se-or-stackoverflow-an-appropriate-forum-for-questions-about-magm#comment86041_22052); hopefully it finds a home here.

> Suppose one has constructed a polynomial algebra $A$ over a ring $R$ in Magma. How does one construct the sub-$R$-algebra of $A$ generated by a given list of elements of $A$?

This seems to me to be a very basic operation so I can't believe there isn't a way to do it, but I haven't so far found it in [the handbook](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/). (I see functionality to construct subalgebras of matrix algebras and of endomorphism rings of abelian varieties, but not polynomial rings.)

**EDIT 11/3/15:**

1) As the functionality of Magma may vary with the ring $R$, take $R=\mathbb{Z}$.

2) hardmath suggests in comments to construct the desired subring as the quotient of another polynomial ring. I take him to mean as the image of a map from another polynomial ring. I tried to implement this in a test case as follows:

```
A := PolynomialRing(IntegerRing(), 3);
s1 := ElementarySymmetricPolynomial(A,1);
s2 := ElementarySymmetricPolynomial(A,2);
s3 := ElementarySymmetricPolynomial(A,3);
B := PolynomialRing(IntegerRing(),3);
f := hom< B ->A | s1,s2,s3>;
S := Image(f);
```

I get a `Runtime error: No constructor provided for this type of object` message when Magma tries to implement `Image(f)`.

Comment: In principle one could construct a subring of a polynomial ring as the quotient ring of an evaluation homomorphism on a "bigger" polynomial ring.  Whether this is computationally attractive might depend on just what you want to do with the subring once you have it.

Comment: @hardmath - I'll try that. (I.e. construct $f:R[T_1,\dots,T_m]\rightarrow A$ by mapping the $T$'s to my desired algebra generators, and then take Image($f$).) Do you know if Magma can intersect ideals of $A$ with Image($f$)?

Comment: I have some other ideas, but I thought you should propose a particular ring as the base for polynomials so we can compare approaches.  Eg. polynomials over the integers, a field, or something more exotic.

Comment: @benblumsmith: Could you move your aside question to a question on SciComp meta?

Comment: @GeoffOxberry - done! http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/457/computer-algebra-tag

Comment: @hardmath - Okay, let's say $R=\mathbb{Z}$. (Should I edit the question?)

Comment: Sure, comments are ephemeral and the Question is best reference.